# Xamarin.Android: Click event on Textview inside list view cell called multiple times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a list view in which inside each cell I have two textview, I need to handle the click event for one of the textview element. But when I put the click event inside the GetView() of the adapter, it is called multiple times.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = tableItems[position];
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.From(mContext);
                view = layoutInflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.myListViewCell, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvEmpName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_EmpName);
                holder.tvEmpPhone = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_EmpPhone);
                view.Tag = holder;
            }

            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;
            }

            holder.tvEmpName.Text = item.FullName;
            holder.tvEmpPhone.Text = item.Phone;

            holder.tvEmpPhone.Click += (sender, e) => {
               // Click event to launch the Popup menu
               // This event is being called multiple times, as Get view() being called multiple times.
            };

            return view;
   }
```

I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263854/click-method-inside-getview-called-multiple-times) similar thread, but didn't find any solution.

Comment: I tested your code without using `ViewHolder`, just access two `TextView` using `view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.;`, the click event will be fired only once when the `TextView` is clicked.

Comment: Grace Feng : In that case it is returning the invalid text string on tap of that textview, as the textview hold different data for each list view cell

Comment: Really? I customized a adapter which inherit from `BaseAdapter<string>`, it works fine. It returns exactly the item I clicked. I can't imagine what happens here, do you need my demo for testing? Or maybe you can share your demo to me?

Comment: In  case of my adapter which inherit from BaseAdapter<Model>, and it is returning sometimes valid and sometimes invalid as I scroll the list perform any kind of search in that case my list refreshes...and on tap it returns invalid string of the textview which is pone number in my case.

Comment: I am trying to implement IOnClickListener interface, once I get it woking fine, I will update my answer, still, if you get any resource plz update..

Comment: I'm now discussing with my friend about your issue, we both cannot reproduce this issue. We can only think about that unless you also register the click event in some where else, this event should only be fired once. The `ViewHolder` here is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The event is called multiple times because evertime when the metod getview is called you add a click event with `+=`.

In this case you can put the click event inside the if, like that:

```
if (view == null)
{
      LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.From(mContext);
      view = layoutInflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.myListViewCell, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.tvEmpName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_EmpName);
      holder.tvEmpPhone = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_EmpPhone);
      view.Tag = holder;
      holder.tvEmpPhone.Click += (sender, e) => {
           // Code here
      };
}
```

But the **recyclerview** is better than listview for this.

Comment: In that case, when you tap on any item cell, the returned Item is invalid. It picks up the the top item.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know RecyclerView? It's the best way implement that.